# MAUI Why is Binding for Padding on ViewModel is not working?

Tags: maui, observableobject

I have a own MyContentPage inherited from ContentPage.
Inside I use a ContentPresenter and I want to set dynamicaly a Padding via ViewModel.

When I set a fix Padding it works.

```
<ContentPresenter Padding="60" ../>
```

When I use the Binding it does not work.

```
<ContentPresenter Padding="{Binding MyPadding}"../>
```

**How can I bind the Padding value?**

I tried for MyPadding string, int and float.

Xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:offline="clr-namespace:Controls.Offline;assembly=Controls"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Controls.Pages"
             x:DataType="pages:MyContentPageViewModel"
             x:Class="Controls.Pages.MyContentPage2"
             Title="MyContentPage2">

    <ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid RowDefinitions="auto,*">

                <offline:OfflineMarkerView Grid.Row="0" />

                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"
                                  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray90}"
                                  Padding="{Binding MyPadding}" />

            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage>
```

codebehind:

```
public partial class MyContentPage2 : ContentPage
{
    public MyContentPage2()
    {
        Shell.SetTitleView(this, new MyIconTitleView());
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MyContentPageViewModel();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public partial class MyContentPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private float _myPadding;

    public MyContentPageViewModel()
    {
        MyPadding = 50;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Padding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.layout.padding?view=net-maui-8.0) is type `Thickness`, not `float`

Comment: @Jason I changed to: private Thickness _myPadding; But it is not the final solution.

Answer (score 2):

The Binding for ControlTemplate is a little bit different. You may take a look at docs about [MAUI Control templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate?view=net-maui-8.0).

I would like to share two ways of Binding MyPadding property in ViewModel.

### Option 1 Use [TemplateBinding for ControlTemplates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate?view=net-maui-8.0#pass-parameters-with-templatebinding)

> The TemplateBinding markup extension binds a property of an element
> that is in a ControlTemplate to a public property that is defined by
> the templated custom control or templated page.

So we try this,

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"
                  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray100}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.MyPadding}"/>
```

We use `TemplateBinding` to binds to the property of the page. And MyPadding is a property in ViewModel which is set as the BindingContext of the page.

### Option 2 Use x:reference

You may set the name for page who consumes the ControlTemplates, such as `x:Name="this"`. When using Binding for Padding, set the Binding Source to the page using x:reference. Then you could easily bind the Padding value to the MyPadding property in ViewModel

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         ...
         x:Name="this">

...

         <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"
                      BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray100}"
                      Padding="{Binding BindingContext.MyPadding,Source={x:Reference this}}"/>
```

---

Here is the screenshot for setting padding as `MyPadding = 50f;`,

[image]

Please let me know if you have any questions.